Mindmap in Tikz, do not draw edge between parent and child in a path
I have a path in a mindmap (see second example) where I would like to not draw one edge between parent and child.
Starting from this
How to set style of a single edge in the tree (TikZ) ? I played around with the solution and was able to adapt it to a minimal example, not drawing the red edges by deleting draw, simply by removing the draw in emph/.style={edge from parent/.style={red,very thick, draw}} to not draw specific edges
However, in my case I already created a quite advanced and long mindmap in LaTeX with many children of different parents. I now realise I want to "delete" or not draw one edge between the main node and a child.
I know there is a solution with creating a second path instead of a child and connecting them later if needed, as I did in this example:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,positioning,backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Hauptknoten
  \path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white] 
    node[concept] (root) {Root} % Hauptknoten
    child[concept color=orange] {node[concept] (child1) {Child 1}} % Erstes Kind
    child[concept color=blue] {node[concept] (child2) {Child 2}}; % Zweites Kind
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Hauptknoten
  \path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white] 
    node[concept] (root) {Root} % Hauptknoten
    child[concept color=orange] {node[concept] (child1) {Child 1}}; % Erstes Kind
  
  % second node (or larger path)
  \node[concept, concept color=blue, right=1cm of child1, scale=1.5, text=white] (child2) {Child 2};

\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Hauptknoten
  \path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white] 
    node[concept] (root) {Root} % Hauptknoten
    child[concept color=orange] {node[concept] (child1) {Child 1}}; % Erstes Kind
  
  % second node or path
  \node[concept, concept color=blue, right=1cm of child1, scale=1.5, text=white] (child2) {Child 2};
  
  

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \path (root) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (black) to (blue)] (child2);
  \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}


Since there are differences already in this minimal example with some absolute and some relative positions, solution on page 2 would "destroy" my mindmap.
I could not figure out how adopt a solution above, is it simply not possible for path? Would make sense however I would be surprised if the style cannot be changed individually, e.g. making that one edge in the first figure transparent
Thanks for the help

please can you make your examples compilable? that's much more useful than code fragments.

it isn't obvious what solution you're referring to in terms of using a path and then connecting things later. I'm not sure how that fits with the linked answer or the code you give here? note that, as far as I know, \node just is \path ... node .... more likely mindmap is the issue rather than \path.

dear @cfr I created a three-pager with different versions for more compatibility. Thank you for that comment!

child[concept] (child2) {Child 2} edge from parent[edge from parent path=] and child[concept color=blue, edge from parent path=] {node[concept] (child2) {Child 2}} remove the connection between Root and Child 2.
